# Trying to select several options in a checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

Basically I am trying to get a checkbox list to be able to allow me several different options to be selected for "various fees" of an invoice. 
So far, everything is successful, but I can't select multiple fees without the page crashing.

This is an example of how it's supposed to be: http://aspnet.cob.ohio.edu/matta/asppub/MIS3200/Unit4/BobcatU4L22.aspx

This is my current code :

```
if (cblFees.Items[0].Selected)
{
    decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[0].Value);
}
if (cblFees.Items[1].Selected)
{
    decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[1].Value);
}
if (cblFees.Items[2].Selected)
{
    decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[2].Value);
}
if (cblFees.Items[3].Selected)
{
    decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[3].Value);
}
if (cblFees.Items[4].Selected)
{
    decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[4].Value);
}

if (decStateTaxRate == 0.00M)
{
    lblOutputCheckBoxList.Visible = true;
    lblOutputCheckBoxList.Text = "The State Code was not recognized.";
}

if (decStateTaxRate > 0.00M)
{
    decCalculatedStateTax = (decStateTaxRate * decSales);
    decTotalDue = (decCalculatedStateTax + decSales);


    lblOutputCheckBoxList.Visible = true;
    lblOutputCheckBoxList.Text = "Your state is: " + strState + "<br />" + " the tax rate is " + decStateTaxRate + "<br />" +
        "Sales Tax = " + decCalculatedStateTax.ToString("C2") + "<br />" + "Fees (after sales tax) = " + decFees + "<br />" + "Total Due = " + decTotalDue.ToString("C2");
}
```

> ```
> Server Error in '/asppub' Application.
> Input string was not in a correct format.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> ```
>
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Source Error:
>
>
> Line 177:        if (cblFees.Items[0].Selected)
> Line 178:        {
> Line 179:            decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[0].Value);
> Line 180:        }
> Line 181:        if (cblFees.Items[1].Selected)
>
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\asppub\MIS3200\Unit4\RingU4L2.2.aspx.cs    Line:
> ```
>
> 179
>
> ```
> Stack Trace:
>
>
> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>    System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
> ```
>
> +9594763
>          System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +146
>          System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value) +68
>          MIS3200_Unit4_RingU4L1.btnCheckBox_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\asppub\MIS3200\Unit4\RingU4L2.2.aspx.cs:179
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? "The page crashing" is not very helpful.

Comment: Place try, catch and paste the error here, so we understand the exact problem.

Comment: I guess the page literally crashes into pieces

Comment: The problem is that the following value cannot be converted to a decimal: `cblFees.Items[0].Value`. To answer your question it would be helpful if you inspect the value in the debugger and post its content here. Typically these issues are related to culture settings.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simply saying that it can't convert the value of the selected checkbox to a decimal. i.e. the Convert.ToDecimal is failing possibly because either the value of the checkbox list isn't a valid decimal number or it hasn't been set.

```
decFees = decFees + Convert.ToDecimal(cblFees.Items[0].Value);
```

Here's an example of a simpler way of doing what you want, it will attempt to parse the value as a decimal and then add it to the total. You may want to add some exception handling to warn you if the value hasn't been set correctly (otherwise it will just carry on and never add the value to the total).

**Page**

```
<asp:checkboxlist runat="server" ID="MyCheckBoxList">
    <asp:ListItem Value="10.56">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="9.99">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4.56">Item 3</asp:ListItem>   
</asp:checkboxlist>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal total = 0;

    foreach (ListItem item in MyCheckBoxList.Items)
         if (item.Selected)
         {
             decimal selectedValue = 0;

             if (decimal.TryParse(item.Value, out selectedValue))
             {
                 total = total + selectedValue;
             }
         }
}
```